# Multiple closures and ReSharper's "Access to Modified Closure" Warning

Tags: c#, resharper, closures

I've got code like the following:

```
private void SetupCheeseShop(Button buyCheese, Button spoilCheese)
{
    var cheeseCount = 0;    // No cheese

    spoilCheese.Click += (sender, e) => {
        // "Access to Modified Closure" warning occurs for cheeseCount below:
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} cheeses have spoiled", cheeseCount));

        cheeseCount = 0;    // Throw out moldy cheese
    };


    buyCheese.Click += (sender, e) => {
        cheeseCount++;
    };
}
```

ReSharper is warning me that I'm accessing a modified closure when reading from `cheeseCount` in the spoil-cheese handler. Can I safely ignore it in this case?

I'm expecting the cheese count to be modified between calls to the first closure, but I'm not sure what happens when the code doing the modifying is in a second closure around the same variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore the warning in your case. It warns you that the closed over variable can potentially have a different value than the current value (0) at the time the closure is created. That's what you want here. You can have any number of closures, they all reference the same variable. Think of a closure variable as a field in a class (which is what the compiler generates).

As stated in section §5.1.7 of the [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029):

> If the local variable is captured by an anonymous function
>   (§7.15.5.1), its lifetime extends at least until the delegate or
>   expression tree created from the anonymous function, along with any
>   other objects that come to reference the captured variable, are
>   eligible for garbage collection.

You can safely rely on this behavior: the variable stays the same, no matter how many anonymous functions are referencing it, until the event handlers are collected, which won't happen until the buttons themselves are collected in your example.

Comment: I knew the compiler generated classes for some closures, but then wouldn't each closure get its own class (and thus variable)? Or would it just create one class for both closures?

Comment: @Cameron I believe it currently generates a single class, though that's an implementation detail and not in the spec. In fact, there's a decent chance that will change in a future version, since the current implementation can have resource retention issues.

Comment: @dlev: OK. But if each closure had its own class, they'd be accessing different variables, right? Then my example wouldn't work at all.

Comment: @Cameron Right. The example works because there's only a single generated closure class (which you can verify pretty easily with Reflector/ILSpy).

Comment: The specification guarantees that the variable is always the same one. See update of my post.

Comment: @Julien You're right; I got that confused with what happens when two methods close over two *different* variables in the same scope. In that case, I think it's still a single class that is generated (which is what might change.) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @dlev, Julien: Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

Your cheeseCount variable is not a field, and scope of your variable is only within your own method.

You should move your cheeseCount out of your method and make it a field.

Comment: It so happens that this method is a cheese-handler factory (OK, I'm stretching my example a bit), so I want a new `cheeseCount` variable each time my method is called.

Comment: Yes you will have a new variable each time method is called, and new anonymous event handlers with new cheeseCount variable. Where else field makes more sense. In your case it may have worked but there might be cases where it could really give unpredictable results, hence the warning.